# Number of kxk matrices whose rows and columns are permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_k$ be permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. I want to determine the number of $k$-tuples $(\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_k)$ of permutations such that, for each $1\leq j\leq k$, setting $\sigma^j(i)=\sigma_i(j)$ is also permutation. In other words, letting $M_{i,j}=\sigma_i(j)$, what is the total number of $k\times k$ matrices for which each row and each column represents a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$?

Comment: Such objects are called [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Comment: The number of $k\times k$ Latin squares is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002860 --- it only goes to $k=11$.

Comment: No effective general formula or even the asymptotic behaviour is known.

Comment: It is conjectured, I think, that the number of 1-factorizations of $K_n$ is about $(n/e^2)^{n^2/2}$.  Bounds are known, but where the base of the exponent differs by a constant multiple.  We want 1-factorizations of $K_{n,n}$ instead.  Do the techniques extend somehow?  With not much effort we get something in between $(C_1 n)^{n^2/2}$ and $(C_2 n)^{2n^2}$, but there is a huge gap.